# PyScripter - change highlighting options/color scheme Python

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, pyscripter

Just wondering if anyone else is using PyScripter as a Python editing app.

I've been runnign my python IDLE in a black background and now find the default white of PyScripter to be blinding.

For the life of me I can't find the menu to change the "highlighting" portion of the program (where you open and modify .py files).

I did however find some exported configuration files that has already had the changes i want imposed:
http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/Customization

However I'd still like to know how to do it myself so i can spend some quality time with this editor. 
   Thanks!

Comment: +1 never heard PyScripter.  it looks good!

Comment: @Corey Goldberg: My only vice with it is that "task list" almost never auto-refreshes. Otherwise, it is a lot lighter than pydev. It's nice if you're not into vim/emacs. You can also get a portable version of it ... portableapps.com i think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tools > options > editor options. Not being able to find these things really do irk me.

Answer (score 3):

right click on the editor pane, choose editor options, syntax colors and then change the 'space' color to black. You then have to change all the other syntax color options so that you can see them again though!